# Gatsby console.log statements don't get printed

Tags: gatsby

I'm trying to solve an issue on Gatsby by placing some `console.log` statements on critical parts of the code that performs the build. However, these statements are not being printed to the console.

I've also tried using the `debug()` function that is used by Gatsby itself to print things like `"Generating Static HTML"` to the console, but it also doesn't work.

I'm using Gatsby installed locally and running it with `./node_modules/.bin/gatsby build`.

---

Obs.: Log statements on `gatsby/bin/gatsby.js` do get printed, but not those on `gatsby/lib/bin/cli.js` or any other file imported by it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the statements to `gatsby/dist` not `gatsby/lib`. I thought actually that the `lib` folder wasn't distributed... guess we need to fix the `.npmignore` then (https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/pull/609).

Answer (score 1):

every time I run Gatsby, I have to;

`rm public -rf && set DEBUG=SSG* && gatsby develop`

Comment: This doesn't seem to do anything

Answer (score 0):

`console.log` statements that are put inside components get rendered by React on the browser. Therefore, debug output is received by the browser's developer console. I'd advise you to **check your browser's console**.